# Saving variables to arrays that change their name over a loop

Tags: c, arrays, vector

This program that reads the vector(s) variables out of a file, and saves them to an array(s).

I found a way how to calculate the number of vectors, but cannot figure out how to assign different values to them . The name of the vector has to change over the loop, and this is the diffuclt part.I called the length of a vector DIM.

here is my loop:

```
enum {DIM = 3} //length of a vector
int vnumber; //Number of vectors
char vectorname; //Name of the vector

for(i=0; i<= vnumber; i++){
    sprintf(vectorname, "vec_%u", i);

 //Read vector values from a file,assign them to corresponding vector of length DIM

        for(n=0; n<DIM; n++){
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &vectroname[n]);
        }
 //Print out the results
        printf ("Vector &s is: %.3lf  %.3lf  %.3lf \n", 
            vectorname, vectorname[0], vectorname[1], vectorname[2]); 
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question about adding values to vector OR coming up with different names for any number of vectors?

Comment: You can not create variable names dynamically in C. In such cases, we generally use arrays.

Comment: @MayurK Both. It has to dynamacally create new array with new variables.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So, it means that I cannot do it in C? Thanks for answer!

Comment: Yes, you can not create a new  variable name at runtime.